# POST edited data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I got field which is populated with autosuggest. Informations retreived from table are:
project name and project id, like this - project (123) - this is what i have in input field.
How to post just id in another table?

I have insert code that inserts all data - project (123) but how to separate it before post is done and have just id posted?

Thanks

code for insert

```
$save="insert into artefact (name, description, claim, status, location, type, project, creator) 
values ('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['desc']}','{$_POST['claim']}','{$_POST['status']}','{$_POST['location']}','{$_POST['type']}','{$_POST['project']}','{$_POST['creator']}');";
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have and the exact database structure? And best if you could show us the data structure you wish to have at the end.

Comment: If you want to extract the id from `string (theId)`, you'll probably want to use a regex expression to get it out. If that's not what you want, well... Try to be a bit more clear in your question. And P.S. "I have insert code"... I don't see anything? ;) *Add it please* :)

Comment: code for insert added. is it possible to use regex on that post project part - {$_POST['project']} before it is posted?

Comment: Possible MySQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

I would  modify that autosuggest script to insert project id in seperate hidden field and then use it to save data.